# How to unit test Unity code with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I've written a feature that I want to unit test. I've been following [Jason Weimann's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCghhGLUa-Y). (I haven't found a tutorial for VS Code, so I went with one on Visual Studio.) Basically, it says:

1. In Unity, go to Window ->  General -> Test Runner.
2. Create an EditMode test assembly folder (creates an asmdef file by itself).
3. Create an assembly definition file in the Scripts folder, and reference it from the EditMode asmdef.

As soon as I add the scripts asmdef file, I get a couple of CS0234/CS0246 errors, for example

- The type or namespace name 'InputSystem' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine'
- The type or namespace name 'IInputActionCollection' could not be found

Which are all in the class generated by the new input system. Oddly enough, VS Code doesn't mention a word about these errors.
There are also 2 warnings, both saying "Assembly for Assembly Definition File X will not compile, because it has no scripts associated with it." First one is about the test asmdef, second one about the scripts asmdef.

I thought I'd fix the warnings first. I found [this link](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/collaborate-assembly-definition-file-warning-message-when-starting-new-project) which says the issue is fixed with Unity 2020.1.3f1, so I upgraded the project version to 2020.1.6f1. Poof, warnings are gone - but not the errors.

I also tried what [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cannot-find-unityengine-inputsystem.807645/#post-5401134) said - which is related to the first error above. No success with it.

If that helps, I already have installed the unity package Input System 1.0.0

Where should I go from here?

Comment: If you're like the rest of us, Unit Test? Huh? Wuz that?